# php loop for a amount of times

Tags: php, html

I need to loop a html code with php so it will display a list if messages results if it is possible?

I found this code on google? i couldnt understand it:

```
      $brush_price = 5; 

    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr><th>Quantity</th>";
    echo "<th>Price</th></tr>";
    for ( $counter = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $counter;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $brush_price * $counter;
        echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}
```

I just need it to duplicate a div which is

```
<div class="news" align="center" style="width:900px;height:65px;background-color:#C8C8C8">
<h3> From: ..... </h3></br>
<p1> Message: Thank you for registering... </p1>
</div>
```

and i need to loop it for home much messages he has

Comment: What is a `<p1>` tag? I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist in HTML...

Comment: If you're having trouble with the PHP can you provide us with a good example of the HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
?>
    <div class="news" align="center" style="width:900px;height:65px;background-color:#C8C8C8">
    <h3> From: ..... </h3></br>
    <p1> Message: Thank you for registering... </p1>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Although, as @mc10 stated, `<p1>` is not a valid HTML tag.  This code will duplicate that HTML ten times.  To change the number of times it duplicates, change the number in the loop (`$i < 10`).

The sample code is a basic for loop, like I used here.  The manual on the `for` control structure is here:

http://php.net/for

I recommend that you read a tutorial on the basics of PHP.

http://devzone.zend.com/article/627

Answer (score 0):

This is a for loop:

```
for ( $counter = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10) {
```

It starts at 10, $counter, and then will continue until that counter is greater than 100.  Every time it runs that code, it will increase by ten.  You can duplicate your div by putting a for loop around it like this

```
<?php
for( $i = 0; $i < NUMBER_OF_TIMES_TO_RUN; $i += AMOUNT_TO_ADD_EACH_TIME) {
?>
    HTML
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually, NUMBER_OF_TIMES_TO_RUN isn't an accurate "constant", as the actual number of times the thing will run is NUMBER_OF_TIMES_TO_RUN/AMOUNT_TO_ADD_EACH_TIME (using your variables)